# NullPointer when sending strings between different Packages

Tags: java, android, exception, nullpointerexception

I am trying to pass a string array of `_imagesPaths` from one package to another.

I have tried the following:

```
//sending the paths of images from `MainActivity` which is in `main.packages`
//assume the array is not null

Intent b = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditPicturesActivity.class);
b.putExtra("left",LeftImageString);
b.putExtra("right",RightImageString);
```

The paths are received in another package by doing the following:
        `private String[] _imagesPath;`
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    _imagesPath[0] = extras.getString("left");
    _imagesPath[1] = extras.getString("right");

Next, I try to load images supplied by the paths but I get a `NullPointer` which says `_imagesPath is null`.

**EDIT**

The value of _imagesPath is assigned by doing selecting an image from gallery:
In this activity

`private String[] _imagesPath = null;`

```
case SELECT_PICTURE1:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            LeftImageString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

            cursor.close();

            //the toast displays the path and it is not null
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "The path of the first image you have selected is:  "
                            + LeftImageString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            // String leftImagePath contains the path of selected Image


            //intent for "left" is placed here

        }      
        break; 

//similary image is taken for Image 2.
```

Comment: Where do you set value to `_imagesPath`?

Comment: How do you initialise _imagesPath?

Comment: You are setting _imagespath to null. Why are you surprised that a null exception is thrown?

Comment: Changed it according to the answer below. Still the same problem at the same location.

Answer (score 0):

you must initialise _imagesPath before you set values to it:

```
String _imagesPath[] = new String[2];
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();            
_imagesPath[0] = extras.getString("left");
_imagesPath[1] = extras.getString("right");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly pass _imagesPaths like,

```
Intent b = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditPicturesActivity.class);
b.putExtra("paths",_imagesPaths);
```

And can get it on other end like,

```
String[] paths = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("paths");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, but you need to initialize your image array.

Thank you.

Comment: I did just as Hasan's answer states